# Displaying a tree structure in Silverlight MVVM

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, hierarchy

I have a list of objects in a tree structure obtained from the database.
When the page is loaded there is a combo box that represents the top level in the hierarchy. When the user selects an item in the combo box, there should be another combo box (dynamic) that shows all the elements in the second level. when the user selects an item in the second combo box, its children should be shown in another combo box. this should continue till the last element in the hierarchy. Can anyone show me how to implement this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a tree type view? Multiple combobox's seems rather cumbersome.

Comment: I want the users to know the children only after they select the parent. And in my application tree type view is not acceptable.